# How do I AVERAGEIF by only changing the Criteria but keeping the rest the same

Tags: excel, average

From the list of products, I took the unique values for a certain month. I want to compute the average of every product. The issue is, as you can see in the picture, RANGE and AVERAGE_RANGE parameters move alongside the CRITERIA.

I need those to stay in place and only move down the filtered column (CRITERIA).

I only need the values for May, so (D7:D29, CRITERIA, F7:F29)

[image: EXCEL EXAMPLE]

Comment: `=AVERAGEIF(D$7:D$29,J8,F$7:F$29)`.

Comment: youre one of a kind! Thank you!